# How do I go back to KDE splash / login after installing XFCE?

Tags: kde, login-screen, plymouth

I started with Ubuntu Karmic, and wanted to try KDE. So I installed `kubuntu-desktop`. Then I wanted to see how XFCE progressed, so I installed `xfce4`. I now have Kubuntu with an XFCE splash and login.

How do I (safely) purge XFCE and just have the Kubuntu splash / login screen, or am I stuck with frank-en-buntu?

Comment: I think you should edit the question to something like "How do I go back from XFCE to KDE?". 

The current question is too vague and informal, and honestly, every time I saw it in the homepage I just ignored it thinking it was something like "help me! I'm f***g crazy about Ubuntu and won't go back to Windows!!!!" :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

splash screen is configured by the alternatives system... you can get a list of available plymouth themes by doing: `update-alternatives --list default.plymouth`

You can then change the current plymouth theme by doing
`sudo update-alternatives --set default.plymouth /lib/plymouth/themes/kubuntu-logo/kubuntu-logo.plymouth`

The alternative way of getting Kubuntu splash it to remove package **xubuntu-plymouth-theme**.

To change the login screen you can either run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm` and choose kdm as mentioned in another comment or remove **gdm** which should set kdm as default display manager.

Answer (score 6):

You can just switch back the display manager to use kdm using

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

and then selecting kdm.

Comment: kdm is the display manager, its the splash and login I'm trying to fix :)

Comment: Well, the display manager is actually what greets you, and asks for the login.
I use this to switch between kdm, gdm and others.
Is your gdm rather messed up? Then there's some system preferences app to select another theme maybe?

Answer (score 3):

From a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove xfce4
```

Comment: That will revert the splash screen as well as the login? I almost did that, but grew hesitant.

Comment: It probably should... I imagine that when the xfce4 package is removed, it restores the splash screen, etc. from before it was installed.

Comment: I also think you meant `remove` , not `uninstall`?

Comment: @Tim: He-he... my bad.

Comment: I'm skeptical...I removed xfce4 once, and I still saw the xfce4 shutdown screen every time I shutdown or restarted.

Answer (score 0):

Also after you remove xfce and all other apps, reinstall ubuntu-desktop to make sure you get everything back

Comment: -1 That will not bring back the **Kubuntu** splash screen as mentioned in the question.